# How to stop Playing video in the background when popup modal is closed or click on out side of the popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento2

I have a button. When user click on button i am showing the video in popup modal. But when i click on outside of the popup the popup is closing but video is keep playing in background and also when i close the popup modal without pausing the video it keeps playing in the background.

How to stop the video playing in the background and reset to starting of the video when popup closed or when we click on outside of the popup.

I have added this code in the page builder for playing video in the popup

```
<button type="button" class="action" data-trigger="trigger">
    <svg xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 2c5.514 0 10 4.486 10 10s-4.486 10-10 10-10-4.486-10-10 4.486-10 10-10zm0-2c-6.627 0-12 5.373-12 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12-5.373-12-12-12zm-3 18v-12l10 6-10 6z" style="fill:#fff" /></svg>
</button>
<div data-bind="mageInit: {
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal':{
            'type': 'popup',
            'trigger': '[data-trigger=trigger]',
            'responsive': true,
            modalClass: 'nursery-modal',
            'buttons': [{
                class: 'action'
            }]
        }}">
    <div class="content">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PRajg7kFcZQ?autoplay=0" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow=accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @ItzHex thanks for you responce. but its not answering my question.

Comment: you can remove the iframe's `src` completely when you click outside of the modal and then apply the `src` when the modal is opened again. this wont pause the video, but rather stop the video entirely and make the user load the entire video again. AFAIK, you can't pause a youtube iframe like the way you want to.